# How do I lock Android Tablet Browser Flash movie to landscape when in fullscreen mode

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3, orientation, web

I have an as3 built osmf video player swf that we embed on a standard HTML page. 
When you touch the image the video automatically goes fullscreen and begins playing. 
Droid and Flash often break after changing back and forth between landscape and portrait while in fullscreen.(by break I mean freeze, where you can hear the video and use the controls, but everything is just a still frozen image, the redrawing fails).
Can you lock the fullscreen orientation in html, javascript, or do you have to try to handle it inside the swf?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ensure you're using Flash Player 10.1.105.6 or later. Locking orientation was successfully added in that version (http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/860/cpsid_86018.html).

After that it should be as easy as setting the autoOrients property of the Stage to false.

```
Stage.autoOrients = false;
```

And manually dictating the orientation:

```
Stage.setOrientation(StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT);
```

There are other Stage properties that can list what orientations are available or test if switching is possible. They're all in the Stage as3 reference.

(http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#autoOrients)

(http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#setOrientation())